# How to configure SpecCPU so that it does not generate cross numa node data transmission?

Tags: performance, benchmarking, numa

We want to evaluate the expected performance of the server using speccpu2017. In our working scenario, **an application instance will be independently deployed on each numa node, and there will be no data communication between instances**. However, progress belong to same instance may have shared variables and shared memory within a numa node.

Therefore, when using speccpu for evaluation, we hope to also simulate such scenarios, so that speccpu can **avoid the impact of data transmission across numa nodes when running benchmark**.

How could I configure it? I did not find the corresponding information in the speccpu document.

Comment: Presumably that would depend on the OS.  Most have ways to restrict a thread to a set of cores (affinity), e.g. Linux `taskset`.  For a specific machine with a known set of NUMA domains, you could just manually construct lists of CPU numbers.